# IONIC Search button displaying the list item but need to enable the selection as well

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to provide a list for the Search option to auto complete, And the html element is as below

```
<ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="myInput" [showCancelButton]="shouldShowCancel" (ionInput)="filterItems()" (ionCancel)="onCancel($event)">
</ion-searchbar>
<ion-grid no-padding><ion-list >
 <ion-item *ngFor=" let item of filtereditems" color="silver" >
                          {{item.title}}
 </ion-item></ion-list> 
</ion-grid>
```

The corresponding search.ts file is as below

```
export class SearchPage{
 searchOptions: string = '';
    notesList: any;
    filtereditems:any;

constructor(){
 this.searchOptions= [
            {title: 'London'},
            {title: 'Bristol'},
            {title: 'Cardiff'},
            {title: 'Edinburgh'},
            {title: 'Belfast'},
            {title: 'Newcastle'}
            ];
            this.filtereditems=[];
}

  filterItems(){
        console.log(this.reasonForWithdrawal);
        this.filtereditems=this.notesList.filter((item) => {
            return item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.reasonForWithdrawal.toLowerCase()) > -1;
        })
    }
}
```

All the city list is appearing currenlty, but I need to enable the option to select the right option by clicking on that as well. Any inputs please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allow the user to select one of the options, you just need to handle the `click` event

```
<ion-grid no-padding><ion-list >
    <ion-item *ngFor=" let item of filtereditems" (click)="onSelectItem(item)" color="silver">
        {{item.title}}
    </ion-item></ion-list> 
</ion-grid>
```

And add a method in your component to decide what to do with the selected item:

```
public onSelectItem(item: any): void {
    // Use the selected item...
    console.log(item.title);
}
```

Comment: @sebeferras Not sure if I can ask a different question on the same tread. Kindly let me know if that is not acceptable. I have a toggle screen which changes the search options. I added a segment to Toggle two options and everytime when I click on that it changes the search option. However the previous list is displayed in the ion-list until the I type some characters. This is confusing. Is there a way to either clean the list  or hide the ion-list. I already tried ng-If command and it is not working.

Comment: I'll suggest to create a new question, adding as much code as possible so we can see how to reproduce the issue (feel free to paste the link of the new question here so I can find it easier btw)

Comment: Sure. The link is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52571622/ionic-autocomplete-option-in-search-text-not-disappearing-after-selection